# Не могу подключиться к удаленному серверу postgresql напрямую

Tags: база-данных, ubuntu, postgresql, сервер

такой вопрос, я запустил сервер на vps машине, настроил ssh, по этому ssh подключаюсь к бд через pgAdmin, подключается моя api, которая написана на Spring Framework, но не могу подключиться WPF приложением на c# и через pgAdmin, используя не ssh, я прямой подключение. Проверил все конфиг файлы, открыл доступ подключения любыми ip, открыл порт 5432 в ufw, но ничего не помогает. Помогите пожалуйста.

Мой pg_hba.conf

````
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32             scram-sha-256
host     all            all             0.0.0.0/0                md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                  scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256```
````

Comment: 1. вообще очень плохая идея. 2. не приведены логи попыток подключения. 3. ничего нет про банальную попытку подключиться telnet-ом.

Comment: а как тогда правильно? Я ничего не знаю про удаленные подключения, для меня это в новинку, поэтому и прошу помощи

Comment: так у вас же в начале вопроса и упомянут вполне годный вариант: через ssh-туннель.

Comment: субд случаем слушает не локалхост, а все сетевые интерфейсы?

Comment: На счет ssh все равно хочется разобраться с вопросом о прямом подключении, потому что у c# как-то скудно в этом плане, а также непонятно почему spring проект спокойно коннектиться к удаленной бд, а насчет что слушает субд, а как это можно проверить?